# Android - Permit closing an app / "Hotel-Mode"

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I've searched a lot to find informations about an Android kind-of "Hotel"-Mode. - Found nothing useful so far.

**What i want to achieve:**

I have an existing phonegap-app built for android in HTML5/JS. 
This APP should run on several Tablets (not distributed via AppStore) in a company (mounted on walls). I would like to **forbid** everyone, without a certain pincode/password, to close the app.

I've experienced this on iOS as a User of an HotelApp.

Is this possible on Android? - If so, how?

Comment: I don't quite understand. What would keep anyone from closing the app to begin with, by simply pressing the home button? Or do you want an actual "Exit" button within the app?

Comment: i would like that the tablet is "locked" on this particular application. 
You should not be able to close it.
If you try to close it, a confirmation-window - aksing for a password/pin - should show up.

Comment: Your question is misleading then, because it asks for the opposite. The only way to do what you want that I know of is to have the app replace the launcher.

Comment: @JensNeubauer sorry, you're right - i've edited the question. 

I still found no way, without customizing anything else than the app itself, to be able to integrate this feature. I will update this thread, if we will come to a solution for this.